# String replace in JavaScript (like Query Binding)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Thank you for answering my question, I think this is not interpolation so I change the title and before you mark this as **duplicate** as string interpolation in JavaScript please read the question **carefully**, because I already read the other interpolation question for JavaScript but not one of them is have the same way that I want for my code (I tell the reason on the question), and I don't want to use Plugin.

Hi all, first I want you to know about my purpose in this code, you can tell this main reason is to build Query Binding for Express with MySQL, but I will use this code for other reason also.

I want to know about string interpolation in Javascript / Typescript that will work like Query Binding in code in Code Igniter [source](http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-insert-query/)

```
// Code 1
let person = 'ujang'
let age = 23

console.log("Hello, %s. You're age is %d years old.", person, age)
// Hello, ujang. You're age is 23 years old.

// The function is similiar to this code
// $sql = "insert into tbl_user (name, age, groupname) values (?, ?, ?)";
// $this->db->query($sql,array('codeigniter, 35, 'Group 1'));
```

As can you see in above code I use console.log and it's working as I want it, but because the console.log is void and not returning any value I can't use it in real condition.

```
// Code 2
const str = 'helow, %s. and you want %d piece of cake.?'
const name = 'ujang'
const want = 13

const myFunction = (value, ...optionalParams) => {

    // The function I want is similiar with Query Binding in Code Igniter
    // And it can handle dynamicly params
    // This only sample
    value = value.replace('%s', optionalParams[0])
    value = value.replace('%d', optionalParams[1])
    return value
}

myFunction(str, name, want)
// helow, ujang. and you want 13 piece of cake.?
```

In Code 2 I'll try making a function, that working as expected, but only for static params.

```
// Code 3
const names = 'ujang'
const arg1 = 'good' 
const argN = 'better'

const dontWantFunction = (value, arg1, argN) => {

    return `helow, ${value}, this function is ${arg1} but any ${argN} solution.?`
}

dontWantFunction(names, arg1, argN)
// helow, ujang, this function is good but any better solution.?
```

In Code 3 is function that I don't really want, because is hard to manage and have more hardcode text inside the function.

Is anyone know how to fill `myFunction` in `Code 2`.?

or anyone working on similar code.?

or know some documentation / article that will lead me to this solution.?

I'am waiting for your response that will help me a lot,
Thank you for attention.

Comment: no, that will look like Code 3 in my question. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: There are 18 answers on that question. All 18 will look like Code 3?

Comment: oh sorry @HereticMonkey, previously i read only the corrent answer, but yeah some of it use `${}` and 'str' + 'str', and the other using plugin Kiwi and sprintf. that not really what i want for this code.

Comment: The answer with the check mark is the *accepted* answer, which just means it helped the original asker the most. It does not mean that it is only correct answer, or even correct at all.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, but from the 18 answer i don't see similar answer that i want, the nearest is the Kiwi plugin and the prototype way, but that not the way i want for my code. and I already have the answer below. but thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, where we take out the values from `optionalParams` in sequential manner and replace on matching value

```js
const str = 'helow, {{value}}. and you want {{value}} piece of cake.?'
const name = 'ujang'
const want = 13

const myFunction = (value, ...optionalParams) => {
  return value.replace(/\{\{value\}\}/g, (m) => optionalParams.shift() || m)
}

console.log(myFunction(str, name, want))
```

Comment: Well. thank you so much for your fast response @CodeManiac.
can you costum {{value}} for more shorter than {{v}} .?

Comment: @Sae yes you can use whatever you want instead of `{{value}}`, you can replace `{{value}}` by `{{v}}` and in replace change the pattern to `\{\{v\}\}`

Comment: I got it, change to {{value}} with ? and regex with /\?/.